# How to prevent 2 MySQL processes from updating the same table at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, locking

I need to write a MySQL stored procedure that will execute multiple queries/logic. However, there is a table that is used in this procedure which is also used by other stored procedure. I need to prevent the two procedures from reading/writing to the same table while one is in the middle of an execution.

I need somehow to lock the shared table so no other procedure can use it until locking procedure unlocks it.

Additionally, there are other tables involved in the procedure that I do not want to lock at all. The lock should be placed on some tables and not all of them. All of my tables are using InnoDB storage engine.

Here is what I tried

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test` ()
BEGIN

SET autocommit = 0;
LOCK TABLES db.table WRITE, db.table READ;

START TRANSACTION;
END
... Query 1 SELECT * FROM table1...
... Query 2 UPDATE table1...
... Query 3 INSERT INTO table1...
... Query 4 INSERT INTO table1...
... Query 5 UPDATE table1...
... CALL db.pro1; -- this second procedure makes updated to table1
... Query 6 SELECT * FROM table1...

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

But this is giving me the following error

> ERROR 1314: LOCK is not allowed in stored procedures

How can I lock the shared table in the stored procedure to prevent 2 processes from using the it until the first running procedure finish executing?

Comment: Not sure about the procedure, but have you tried [`SELECT... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) instead of LOCK?

Comment: @rlanvin I have many queries in this procedure that are using the shared table. I even call another procedure from with in the procedure that insert/update/select from that table

Comment: What about moving the lock outside then? LOCK, CALL sp_test, UNLOCK

Comment: this is an option but I will have to keep writing my code every time I want to call the procedure. I am hoping of a smarted way where I don't have to keep writing the code. it seems that if I execute SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE after I start the transaction that should prevent the table from being updated until the final commit takes place

Comment: You are inside a transaction.  None of the updates are committed until it hits the `COMMIT` I don't know what the db.pro1 does but it is attempting to do it within the first transaction and I suspect it is executing inside an implicit transaction, which may end up committing before the finish of the first proc.